# How / when would I package interfaces with clients?

Tags: oop, interface, package

'Uncle Bob' Martin makes a good argument in 'Agile Software Development' pp318-9 that 'Interfaces belong to the client, not to the derivative ... clients tend to be packaged with the interfaces they control'.

In practice, how do people package interfaces with clients in statically typed languages?  From the point of view of the individual interface - where a good OO interface has several implementations - Martin's recommendation makes sense.  But at the package level, there are typically many clients to each server, and having the server depend on its clients seems to make the dependency arrow point in the wrong direction.  Indeed, later in the 'Principles of Package Design' Martin introduces a maxim 'Depend in the direction of stability' which intuitively suggests client -> server.

Answer (score 0):

'Uncle Bob' is correct, but his advice is not always practical. When building a commercial 3rd party library, it is obviously not pracitcal to collect required interfaces from all future customers. That being said, the approach of designing the interfaces to satisfy all known use cases remains valid. Conceptually the interfaces belong to the clients, not the library.

When building in-house utilities, package the interfaces directly with the clients just as 'Uncle Bob' suggests.